# Cannot link Fabric app to Firebase Crashlytics

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric

I know there have been a few questions along these lines but my case doesn't seem to fit any of those.

I have gotten as far as setting up the firebase account and can add the app and it gets analytics.  But if I go to Fabric and go to the 'Link your apps to Firebase' page, the drag area does nothing as it says the app is already linked:

[image: screen cap showing app is linked]

If I try that url with the CLIENT_ID and PROJECT_ID I get the message "Unable to find app  in project . Return to Firebase Console and try again."

So is there a way to get it linked or find information about the existing link?

Comment: Contact Firebase support directly if you're having problems with managing your app in the Firebase or Fabric consoles.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the user needed customer support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was that there was another account linked to the app. An account that I must have made at some point, as the recovery email was one of mine, but I do not remember creating at all.  Once support helped figure that out, was able to get things set up appropriately.